# cygwin terminal colors fade when sshing

Tags: windows, ssh, colors, cygwin

When I ssh into a server, my entire cygwin terminal entirely dims and the colors become more muted. I only think it happens when I ssh into one particular server (this is the only server I actually have ssh access for, but I tried another random server online and my colors didn't fade when I sshed into the other one).

Here's a gif of what happens in my terminal (ignore the random fd): http://i.imgur.com/ieazlKX.gifv

Is this a problem with how the server I'm sshing into configures things?
Because I used to use the MobaXTerm shell before to ssh and the colors in that were still vibrant when I sshed into the same server.

Answer (score 0):

When you ssh into a remote server, it has its own environment variable settings, including `LS_COLORS`.  Normally that would correspond with the color scheme known to [`dircolors`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html#dircolors-invocation). But a while back, Red Hat introduced a change to the *environment variable* to eliminate the **bold** flag (ostensibly to gain a few more characters in the UTF-8 console).  If you don't plan to use colors, that sounds like an improvement.

Many terminals render the **bold** video attribute with a brighter color (rather than switching to a bold font).  There are two reasons for this:

- VGA displays have limited support for mixing fonts (a **bold** font and *italic* are different).
- VGA displays supported 16 colors, ANSI defined 8, so it was a natural way to use the extra colors.

To see the difference, you might try

```
ls
unset LS_COLORS
ls
```

From comments about http://pastebin.com/Gi8A5CmR, the remote machine is modifying the terminal's color palette, i.e., in the line beginning with this text (shortened here for readability):

```
^[]4;0;rgb:18/18/18^[\^[]4;1;rgb:ab/46/42^[\^[]4;2;rgb:a1/b5/6c^[\^[]4;3;rgb:f7/ca/88^[\^[]4;4;rgb:7c/af/c2^[\^[]4;5;rgb:ba/8b/af^[\^[]4;6;rgb:86/c1/b9
```

Those are setting

- each of the colors in the 16-color palette,
- the colors that might be used for bold, underline, reverse and blink,
- plus the dynamic foreground/background colors

These are all documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls) (see the description for *Ps* = 4, 10 and 11).  Recent Cygwin uses mintty, which recognizes a fair number of these sequences. MoabXterm is based on putty, which does not recognize those sequences (that I recall...).  So you see the problem using Cygwin.

There's no "reset palette to default" control sequence.

It's possible to construct a script that sets those back to some value, but it might be simpler to install `xtermcontrol` on a machine to record your initial palette, e.g., using its `--get-colorN` option, and use that in another script to make `xtermcontrol` generate a set of escape sequences that you could just `cat` to the terminal, resetting the palette.

There's not been a lot of attention to this area (to restore settings), since most of the palette manipulation (that I've seen) has been brute-force scripts that work with the 256-colors.  Checking now on my Fedora23, I can see that it does this if I connect having `TERM=xterm-256color`.

If you ensure that `TERM` is set to `"xterm"` when connecting to that server, it probably will not reset your palette.

Further reading:

- [dircolors - color setup for ls](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dircolors)
- [dir_colors - configuration file for dircolors(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors)
- [Aren't bright colors the same as bold?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#bold_vs_16colors) (xterm FAQ)

Comment: I tried doing the unset LS_COLORS, but I saw no difference http://i.imgur.com/hmhs3c2.png

Comment: odd - that's usually enough to fix things with Red Hat.  Of course, they *could* have patched `ls` to match the favored non-bold colors.

Comment: also, even after I logout of my ssh session, the colors are still muted in my regular console

Comment: oh I should also mention that I have `ls` aliased as `if [[ uname = "Darwin" || uname = "FreeBSD" ]]; then
    alias ls='ls -G'
  else
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
  fi
`

Comment: Alternatively, that server *could* be setting the color palette (for someone's "color theme").  I'd take a look by running just a connection to the server with `script` to capture the text, and use `cat -v` to see what escape sequences were in it.  If you were able to paste that in readable form, I could make some suggestions about the actual cause.

Comment: I missed the comment about Darwin/etc.  What type of server are you connecting to (with the problem)?  I'd suspect Linux (with the `--color=auto` feature).

Comment: Yeah, it's a redhat linux